# How to make sure XCode project is NOT IPad deliverable?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have developed my whole app assuming it would be available for iphone and ipad, after business decision, I have removed the ipad storyboard and submited to App Store.

It was rejected due the app is "blank" on IPad tests...

How Do I make sure the App is going to run only in IPhone? apparently just deleting the storyboard is not enough.

thanks

Comment: It is not duplicated, you didn't understand the question.

Comment: That duplicate link doesn't explain how to change the build setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In project Summary settings, set the Devices from `Universal` to `iPhone`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In project summary under ios application target tab
Set the Deployment target to iPhone